# Reproducing Excel's worksheet Checksum/hash ID

Tags: microsoft-excel

To start, when you have an Excel file, you can rename it as a .zip file to show the guts/interior of the spreadsheet. Ok, all good.

Inside of the xl folder, you get all of the spreadsheets as a .xml. You can click on them, and open them. I imagine you can also edit and save them.

However, each sheet has a checksum/hash field associated with it. I imagine if the checksum/hash doesn't match, it throws an error (possibly a corruption error).

I haven't gotten around to testing it, but that interests me slightly less than the question - how can I take a .xml file, and generated the corresponding hash?